# Is it legal to just replace an existing extractor fan in a shower room with a similar model?

Tags: electrical, bathroom

The existing ceiling mounted fan is not working correctly now. It is wired via an isolating switch high up in the room away from the shower. The fan has a built-in pull cord: pull for on, pull again for off. There is no timer. I just want to replace it with a similar model. The electrician advises that I must fit a low-voltage model with an isolating switch and transformer outside of the shower room, in the bedroom next door. The existing fan was installed when the house was built 18 years ago. Any advice please?

Comment: Why don't you trust the Electricians advise? It sounds like this is something they should know about, being that it's their job and all.

Comment: I assume this is in UK? Based on pull- cord fan

Comment: Do you know the root cause of why the fan isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The replacement of a device (or any part of a circuit) will likely be subject to all **current** codes, laws, and rules (may not be applicable to cord-and-plug devices). What these "rules" are will depend on your location, so it's difficult to say if it's legal or not without knowing what that location is.

Your best bet would be to contact your local government, and ask what the "rules" are.